# OnItemClickEvent not fired in GridView in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

i m developing an application in which gridview contain list of button...

when i place images instead of button in gridview then onItemClickEvent get fired..but if i place button in gridView then click event not getting callled...i dont know what is the problem...even i m not getting exception..

here is my code...

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "hello" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}
//inner class for adapter

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ImageView imageView;
        Button btn;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            btn=new Button(mContext);
       //   imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));
        //  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(140,140));


            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            btn.setPadding(10,15, 10,15);
            btn.setImeActionLabel("hello",0);// actionId)

        //  imageView.setPadding(8,8, 8, 8);

        } else 
        {
            btn=(Button)convertView;
            //imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
        }
        btn.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        //return imageView;
        return btn;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
            R.drawable.pantrylocator_icon,
            R.drawable.volunteeropportunity_icon,
            R.drawable.volunteerlocator_icon,
            R.drawable.volunteermanagement_icon,
            R.drawable.donationform_icon,
            R.drawable.donationviamsg_icon,
            R.drawable.donationvideo_icon,
            R.drawable.virtualfooddrive_icon,
            R.drawable.newevent_icon,
            R.drawable.pressrelease_icon,
            R.drawable.volunteerphotos_icon,
            R.drawable.aboutus_icon,

     };
}
}
```

Comment: Just an assumption, but maybe because a button has it's own OnClickListener.

Comment: I think I had similar issue with GridView. My items didn't contain buttons but I had declared them "clickable" in layout.xml. Removing "clickable" fixed the situation for me - but then again - I wasn't using buttons.

Comment: hey buddy...i have solved probklem...i just define button click event in baseadapter class...and my problem is ssolved........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The button has its own OnClickListener:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ImageView imageView;
        Button btn;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            btn=new Button(mContext);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click
                 }
             });
       //   imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));
        //  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(140,140));


            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            btn.setPadding(10,15, 10,15);
            btn.setImeActionLabel("hello",0);// actionId)

        //  imageView.setPadding(8,8, 8, 8);

        } else 
        {
            btn=(Button)convertView;
            //imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
        }
        btn.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        //return imageView;
        return btn;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your ImageAdapter-> getView method add the following line before returning newly created "convertView"

```
            convertView.setClickable(false);
            convertView.setFocusable(false);
```

If any of the views in gridview are  clickable then they will block the grid's ItemClick listener from responding.

Answer (score 2):

There is no onclick event written for the Buttons you are adding. Write code for the buttons to handle the click event! let us know then.

Comment: hey buddy...i have solved problem...i just define button click event in base adapter class...and my problem is solved........

Answer (score 2):

i have fece this problem also but finally got the solution  i have follow the above suggession

and define button click event in base adapter class like as

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
        View v;

        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

            v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);

             tv = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);

             iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "vim", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

});

        }

        else

        {
            v = (View)convertView;
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gameGrid);
        gridview.setAdapter(ia);            
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Ur Code here
                 }
```

Add click events for the button added in `gridView`

Comment: hey buddy...i have solved problem...i just define button click event in base adapter class...and my problem is solved........

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest way to do it: call performItemClick() on the GridView from within each button's click listener. That way you can still use the GridView's onItemClickListener like normal.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((GridView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/

Answer (score -2):

I have solved my problem as i define button click event in base adpter class and my problem is solved......

Comment: Please write comments below answers of other not as a separate answers..does not make any sense.